# NetBeans 7.2: problems creating and running Maven WebApplications

Tags: web-applications, maven-3, maven-plugin, netbeans-7

In NetBeans 7.2, I get the following behavior:

**1.** Upon hitting the 'run (play)' button on an existing Maven Webapplication, the following error is displayed:

```
cd E:\Dev\Apps\MyApp; JAVA_HOME=E:\\Apps\\Dev\\jdk7u5 E:\\Apps\\Dev\\NetBeans7\\NetBeans7.2.1\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat install
Scanning for projects...
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.154s
Finished at: Mon Nov 19 20:42:10 CET 2012
Final Memory: 2M/15M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (E:\). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

**2.** Upon creating a new Maven Web Application project from the IDE, it ends up in the root of my drive ("E:\") instead of under the one I specified in the project creation dialog window ("E:\Dev\Apps\").

I tried:

- uninstalling and re-installing various versions NetBeans 7.x

  delete env vars, reboot, add correct env vars, reboot,..

  looking in build.properties file (but don't know where to look)

Why is NetBeans reacting like this and what can I do to fix these two problems?

Answer (score 0):

1)
Click on Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced systems settings -> Environment Variables.
In the Environment Variables must be set the JAVA_HOME with the path of jdk and MAVEN_HOME with the path to the folder downloaded from maven. What you should probably have done the powers to install correctly.

2)
Another reason may be giving this problem is due to Settings.xml not be configured correctly in the situation of proxy, you must configure with proxy you're using.
-settings.xml that exists in the system (cmd / terminal).
-settings.xml that exists in your IDE (netbeans or eclipse).

Comment: I tried your suggestions and they didn't fix the problem. Do you think this has something to do with permissions? I even tried installing this with Kaspersky Internet Security 2013 turned off. I am using the Maven installation that was provided with NetBeans 7.2.1. I couldn't find settings.xml, but I configured NetBeans to not use a proxy. I tried "don't use proxy" and "use system settings" as well. None worked. Previous symptoms remain. I still don't know what is causing the problem.

Comment: Did you install Maven like the first point i refer in first point?

Install Maven:

-JAVA_HOME = "C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.6.0_13"

-MAVEN_HOME = "C: \ (located where it was unloaded and unpacked Maven)"

-PATH = (Add Path in the path to the maven) "MAVEN_HOME% \ bin;%"

-Modify the proxy (in the settings.xml file) in the IDE and Maven folders.

-cmd or terminal = mvn-version (to see if it was properly installed maven)

Comment: Technically I didn't install Maven, because I installed NetBeans 7.2.1 and the installer installed its own Maven (3.0.4) for me. That's the Maven that I set as MAVEN_HOME. mvn --version from commandline gives me: Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100). It's the correct output, so that's working. Still, same symptoms. I didn't use the % sign at the end though. I don't know if that's needed. I'm not using any proxy though. This situation is the same at home as it is at my university campus. They use ISA server. Strange, settings.xml from Maven is all commented out.

Comment: The only thing that I think might have something to do with this is the fact that my previous Maven Webapplication was pulled from my campus' svn server. This still doesn't explain why NetBeans creates my projects directly under E:\ and ignores the project path I specified.

Comment: I have also Netbeans7.2.1 and i had to install netbeans, one of the main errors is problems in settings.xml (in windows you can find the file in C:\Users\Kadeshrocha\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\maven\conf) try to use in terminal or cmd the command **mvn -version** to see if the maven is install.

Comment: mvn --version in terminal resolves to correct maven installation that NetBeans 7.2.1 is using and I also saw that everything in settings.xml has been commented out by default. I don't see a problem there.

Comment: **The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (E:\)**
Now i see the problem!!!! You are getting the project in disc E:\ maybe you there dont have any **pom.xml** file there or your MAVEN_HOME is in another directory, try to see the path in the point 1) i refer on top.

Comment: I just deleted MAVEN_HOME to see if that helped. It didn't help. Path of JAVA_HOME: E:\Apps (x86)\Dev\Java\jdk7u7 and MAVEN_HOME: E:\Apps\Dev\NetBeans7\NetBeans7.2.1\java\maven I also have E:\Apps\Dev\NetBeans7\NetBeans7.2.1\java\maven\bin\ in the Path system variable. I have a mix of jdk's in my path. I don't know if this is bad. My project resides in: E:\Dev\2012_2013\Java\MyApp . When I try to run the project, I get the error you just mentioned. So, my app is not directly under E:\. I don't have my projects there and therefor no POM file there, only in E:\Dev\2012_2013\Java\MyApp Any idea?

Comment: MAVEN_HOME: E:\Apps\Dev\NetBeans7\NetBeans7.2.1\java\maven\bin\

PATH:...;%MAVEN_HOME%

JAVA_HOME: look for your jdk 1.7 java file

Change your proxy definitions in setting.xml in IDE (netbeans) and Maven folder to you proxy port the rest.

Comment: I don't have a proxy. It's a direct connection. Building the project from commandline works perfectly, so it must be NetBeans that is messing up.

Comment: See in netbeans options if you have some proxy configuration (Tool->Options->Proxy) maybe thats the problem.

Comment: No, I do not have any proxy configuration.

Comment: try with a proxy config. Change in IDE netbeans, and change in settings.xml that you have in maven folders in IDE netbeas and maven repository.